# Check if token is float alphanumeric or special character.

Tags: c

I use strtok to get the tokens in a line from stdin.

```
    fgets(line,MAXCOLS,stdin);
    printf("line:%s\n",line);
    ch = strtok(line," ");
    while(ch != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n",ch);
        ch = strtok(NULL," ");
    }
```

But how do I find out if my ch is a float, a alphanumeric value or a special character?

Comment: `ch` will always have the same type, `char *`. Depending on your file's encoding (ASCII, ANSI, UTF8, etc...), you can check the values pointed by `ch` as characters to see if they are 0..9, a..z/A..Z, etc...

Comment: The question is, How do I check it? Isnum takes checks for integer values, not floats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ch` is never any of those things. It is *always* a pointer to an array of characters.

You might want to know whether those characters are a *textual representation* of a numeric value. To that end, you can run `strtol()` or `strtod()` on the tokens and see if you succeed. Note that something like `12.34` will be read successfully both as an integer and as a floating point number, so you should supply the second argument to those functions and check that you really reach the end of the token (as opposed to only converting an initial part of the token):

```
char * e;
long int n = strtol(ch, &e, 0);

if (*e != 0) { /* error? */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `is*` family of functions, e.g. [`isalpha()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isalpha/).

But note, this only tells you about the value of **one** character.  A character is just a character, it's not, for instance, a float.